# Calling contextDestroyed Method on webserver shutdown

Tags: java, unix

I have created a webapp which has only one servletContext listner.

Below is the code:
I had tried with `Runtime.getRuntime()` but this didnt work. So while googling came across `ProcessBuilder` but it dont work either.

I can execute the scripts by running from console on UNix box.

Purpose of below code is to execute sh script like capture something like `echo Hello > test.txt` whenever server goes down. But this script doesnot get executed when server goes down. Not sure why `conextDestroyed` is not getting called or if `conextDestroyed` getting called why script is not getting executed.

```
public class MyTestContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","/local/test/tomcatContextTest/tomcatContextListener.sh");
    try {
        pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","/local/test/tomcatContextTest/tomcatStartContextListener.sh");
    try {
        pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: what Webserver do you use?

Comment: Is the contextInitialized method called? Have you considered putting a System.out.println line in them to check if they are called?

Comment: that was typo while posting here... it will be test at both place

Comment: Did you ever put a System.out.println("HERE!") in the methods to check if they are called at all?

Answer (score 1):

Have you put your `ServletContextListener` into your `web.xml`?

Have a look at this example: http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/

Comment: Thanks for reply!!Yes ServelCOntextListener is added in web.xml.

Comment: FYI… Or, as alternative to web.xml, apply the [`@WebListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation to your implementation of the `ServletContextListener`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons the server can go down:

- An internal error (like OutOfMemory) - in this case the ServletContextListener is not invoked
- Somebody kills the Application Server - ServletContextListener is never invoked
- You explicitly stop the context (e.g. in the manager) - ServletContextListener is invoked
- You explicitly stop the whole application server - ServletContextListener is invoked

hth

Comment: Thanks for reply I want to understad if the code above is correct or not.

Comment: Try adding a "pb.waitFor();" so that the process can be executed synchronously!